# Google Cloud Speech API cannot auth in command-line on Raspberry Pi 3 Raspbian OS

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi3, google-cloud-speech

I'm testing out the Google Cloud Speech API command-line on Raspberry Pi 3 Raspbian OS using the gcloud SDK. The [standard procedure](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/getting-started) Google provides worked on my Mac OSX! Attempting it in Raspbian fails.

I tried setting ENV vars like "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" and "GCLOUD_PROJECT", and when that didn't work, I unset those vars and tried running "gcloud **beta** init" instead of "gcloud init". No combination of these works.

Command:

```
curl -v -k -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer `gcloud auth print-access-token`" "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:syncrecognize" -d @sync-request.json
```

(note: for the contents of 'sync-request.json', please see the [quickstart guide example](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/getting-started)).

The error message I'm getting is shown below. It seems the wrong project gets is getting selected:

OUTPUT:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Google Cloud Speech API has not been used in project google.com:cloudsdktool before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/speech.googleapis.com/overview?project=google.com:cloudsdktool then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console API activation",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/speech.googleapis.com/overview?project=google.com:cloudsdktool"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This issue probably exists on Debian as well as Raspbian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the auth issue by specifying "application-default" whenever running "gcloud auth" commands (that means for both login and when printing the access token)

First run:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

*** or you can set the "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" env var instead for your service account's private_key_id.

Next run:

```
curl -v -k -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`" "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:syncrecognize" -d @sync-request.json
```

You should see:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "transcript": "how old is the Brooklyn Bridge"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```